# RealmJS: How to be reactive to changes to objects with inverse relationship

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

Consider a hypothetical schema: we have a Dog object, who's schema has a `linkingObjects` type relationship with a Person object, which in turn has a `linkingObjects` type relationship with a City object.

Now, if my presentation component takes a Dog object as it's prop, and using the inverse relations embedded in it, displays attributes relating to the dog, the person, and the city. **What are my options to react to modifications to attributes of the city object?**

My ideas so far are:

1. I could subscribe to realm's write-transaction notification, but that approach doesn't scale because when the application grows there might be lots of unrelated writes to the realm.
2. I could subscribe to collection notifications, but they don't trigger for changes in inverse object's attributes.

Comment: have you tried adding a collection notification subscription for the inverse collection itself, too?

Comment: Since the props include only a collection of Dog objects, I would have to construct and maintain queries related to all inverse objects. If there is nesting like I mentioned in my example, I think maintaining queries will become non trivial.

Comment: You can work around the issue if you open a second query for the inverse table directly and add a collection notifier for that. But theoretically you're *supposed* to observe the inverse relation result set if you want to see changes in it.